# Strange behaviour Constraint Layout Animation on differente Android versions

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I made an animation to represent the number of players in my Android application (2 players = 2 bottles and so on..).
I'm pretty happy with the result but it is not working on my old device on Android 5.0.
The min SDK Version of the application is 21, so it should be alright.

I want to make an animation like this: [Correct animation on Android 10.0](https://streamable.com/bf745u). But in Android 5.0 we have for some values (eg from 3 to 4 but not from 5 to 4) this behaviour: [Wrong animation on Android 5.0](https://streamable.com/vomhpg).

I tried different layouts, resources and more, but I couldn't get it to work 100% correctly on Android 5.0.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.ChangeBounds;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AnticipateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

public class PickNbrPlayersScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ConstraintLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_pick_nbr_players_2);

        layout = findViewById(R.id.bottles_2);

        nbrPlayers = findViewById(R.id.currentPlayerCountTextView);
    }

    public void decreasePlayerNbr(View view) {
        nbrOfPlayers--;
        if (nbrOfPlayers < 2) {
            nbrOfPlayers = 8;
        }
        nbrPlayers.setText(String.valueOf(nbrOfPlayers));
        playAnimation(nbrOfPlayers);
    }

    public void increasePlayerNbr(View view) {
        nbrOfPlayers = Math.max(2, (nbrOfPlayers + 1) % 9);
        nbrPlayers.setText(String.valueOf(nbrOfPlayers));
        playAnimation(nbrOfPlayers);
    }

    private void playAnimation(int nbrOfPlayers) {
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        int currentLayoutId = getCorrectLayout(nbrOfPlayers);
        constraintSet.clone(this, currentLayoutId);

        ChangeBounds transition = new ChangeBounds();
        transition.setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator(1.0f));
        transition.setDuration(500);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(layout, transition);
        constraintSet.applyTo(layout);
    }

    private int getCorrectLayout(int nbrOfPlayers) {
        int layoutId;
        switch (nbrOfPlayers) {
            case 2:
                layoutId = R.layout.menu_pick_nbr_players_2;
                break;
            case 3:
                layoutId = R.layout.menu_pick_nbr_players_3;
                break;
            case 4:
                layoutId = R.layout.menu_pick_nbr_players_4;
                break;
            case 5:
                layoutId = R.layout.menu_pick_nbr_players_5;
                break;
            case 6:
                layoutId = R.layout.menu_pick_nbr_players_6;
                break;
            case 7:
                layoutId = R.layout.menu_pick_nbr_players_7;
                break;
            case 8:
                layoutId = R.layout.menu_pick_nbr_players_8;
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + nbrOfPlayers);
        }
        return layoutId;
    }
}
```

one of my layouts for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottles_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".menuScreens.PickNbrPlayersScreen">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/nbrplayersback" />


    <!-- Beer Bottles -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beerBottle_2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/beerBottle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/beerBottle_height"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/increasePlayerNbrButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.551"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/beerBottle_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.545"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/beerbottle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beerBottle_1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/beerBottle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/beerBottle_height"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/decreasePlayerButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.231"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.145"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/beerbottle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beerBottle_8"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/beerBottle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/beerBottle_height"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/beerBottle_4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/beerbottle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beerBottle_7"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/beerBottle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/beerBottle_height"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/beerBottle_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/beerbottle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beerBottle_6"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/beerBottle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/beerBottle_height"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/beerbottle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beerBottle_5"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/beerBottle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/beerBottle_height"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/beerbottle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beerBottle_4"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/beerBottle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/beerBottle_height"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/beerbottle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/beerBottle_3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/beerBottle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/beerBottle_height"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/beerbottle" />


    <!-- Buttons and TextViews -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/decreasePlayerButton"
        style="@style/RoundButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="decreasePlayerNbr"
        android:text="@string/minusSign"
        android:textSize="@dimen/menu_decrease_textSize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/currentPlayerCountTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/currentPlayerCountTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/increasePlayerNbrButton"
        style="@style/RoundButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="increasePlayerNbr"
        android:text="@string/plusSign"
        android:textSize="@dimen/menu_decrease_textSize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/currentPlayerCountTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bgImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/currentPlayerCountTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentPlayerCountTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNormalText"
        android:textSize="@dimen/menu_nbr_of_players_textSize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/continueButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continueButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/menu_button_margin_bottom"
        android:onClick="nextMenu"
        android:text="@string/Continue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/subtitle_textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/subtitle_textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subtitle_textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/videoView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/menu_subtext_margin_bottom"
        android:text="@string/subtitle_NbrPlayers"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNormalButton"
        android:textSize="@dimen/menu_subtext_textSize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/videoView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is there any way to fix this strange behaviour? Or is it an version issue?

Thank you for your help and time, have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't view animations because links are broken. Btw I suggest to use transition classes from `androidx` package. I mean use [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/transition)

```
import androidx.transition.ChangeBounds;
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager;
```

instead of this:

```
import android.transition.ChangeBounds;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
```

`android.transition` classes are build into platform, they may contain bugs which will never be fixed.